# same enter and exit animation to all fragments in app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add enter and exit animation to all fragments in my app.

I have to repeat below code every time, when i want to replace fragment.

```
Fragment2 frag1 = new Fragment2();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_in_from_left,
                R.anim.push_out_to_right,
                R.anim.push_in_from_left,
                R.anim.push_out_to_right);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag1);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Is there any common way to apply this animation and i can resuse it in whole app as we can do for activities like:

style.xml

```
 <style name="YourAnimation.Activity" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
 <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/push_in_from_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/push_out_to_right</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@android:anim/slide_in_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@android:anim/slide_out_right</item>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a base fragment and extends all your fragments from that base fragment. Write the fragment transaction animation code in a method , call that method every time you want transactions. Simple

Comment: or static helper ... `Helper.getTransaction(getSupportFragmentManager()) `... which would return `FragmentTransaction`  with CustomAnimations already set

Comment: Can i add something to style.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Create a singular method where which accesses the backstack in a given activity. And enter your above code there.
That should do the trick.

While scaling, you can use the same method to add fragments in stack using the same method with possibly different container id.